# Replace number with symbol in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to replace 0 in a list of lists with dot ".". I aslo need to replace 1 with "o" and 2 with "*"
It should be something like chess board. So far I have this and I am stuck with the replacement. Thank you for your help! :)

```py
chess =[
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 "],
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "],
    ["0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "]]


def prt(n):
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(n[i])):
            if n[j] == "0":
                n[j] = "."
            print(n[i][j])
       
prt(chess)
```

Output should be something like this

[image: Final product]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each list of your list you store one string, i.e. `"0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "`.
So your loop doesn't work:

```py
for i in range(len(n)): 
    for j in range(len(n[i])):  # len(n[i]) is always 1
        if n[j] == "0":  # n[j]: "0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 " equal "0" is False
            n[j]="."
```

A comparison for an individual number won't work.
In order for you to get the individual number you can use the `split` method on the only element of your list. So you need to access it via the `0` index and call `split` on that element.
Build a new list of list for storing the modified values.

Using this, you can expand your `if` logic to check for `"1"` and `"2"` and for any other value to not change the value.

```py
chess = [
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 "],
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "],
    ["0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "]]

def prt(n):
    letters = " abcdefgh"
    # Initialize chessboard with letters
    board = [letters]
    # set enumerates start value to 1
    for i, line in enumerate(n, 1):
        numbers = line[0].split()  # splits at whitespace
        line_list = []
        for num in numbers:
            if num == "0":
                line_list.append(".")
            elif num == "1":
                line_list.append("o")
            elif num == "2":
                line_list.append("*")
            else:
                line_list.append(num)
        # Concatenate current line index at beginning and end of line_list
        board.append([i] + line_list + [i])
    # Append letters as last line of board
    board.append(letters)
    # Print new chess board
    for line in board:
        for el in line:
            print(el, end=" ")
        print()

prt(chess)
```

Changes:

- Setting `letters` as first and last element of `board`
- Make use of built-in function `enumerate`
- Set `start` value of `enumerate` to `1` to get a modified index

This will give you the desired outcome:

```py
  a b c d e f g h 
1 . o . o . o . o 1 
2 o . o . o . o . 2 
3 . o . o . o . o 3 
4 . . . . . . . . 4 
5 . . . . . . . . 5 
6 * . * . * . * . 6 
7 . * . * . * . * 7 
8 * . * . * . * . 8 
  a b c d e f g h
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess if you just need to print the layout, this would be a way to solve it:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

chess = [
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1"],
    ["1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0"],
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1"],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0"],
    ["0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2"],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0"]
]

def prt(chess):
    joined_chars = "".join(chess[0][0].split()) # joining the first list in chess to single string: 01010101
    letters = " ".join([ascii_lowercase[i] for i in range(len(joined_chars))]) # Creating a list of letters that is the length of the joined_chars and joins it with spaces: a b c d e f g h
    print(f"  {letters}") # prints the letters starting with two spaces
    for index, lst in enumerate(chess): # Using enumerate to get the index while running through chess
        printable = lst[0].replace("0", ".").replace("1", "o").replace("2", "*")
        print(f"{index+1} {printable} {index+1}") # prints the index (starts at 0) + 1 to get the correct values.
    print(f"  {letters}") # prints the letters starting with two spaces

prt(chess)
```

Result:

```
  a b c d e f g h
1 . o . o . o . o 1
2 o . o . o . o . 2
3 . o . o . o . o 3
4 . . . . . . . . 4
5 . . . . . . . . 5
6 * . * . * . * . 6
7 . * . * . * . * 7
8 * . * . * . * . 8
  a b c d e f g h
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `replace` function for strings.

```
chess =[
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 "],
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "],
    ["0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "]]


def prt (n):
    new_list = []
    for line in n:
        line = line[0]
        line = line.replace('0','.')
        line = line.replace('1', 'o')
        line = line.replace('2', '*')
        temp = []
        temp.append(line)
        new_list.append(temp)
    print(new_list)
       
prt(chess)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by using the replace function for strings and iterating through the lines itself:

```
def print_chess(chess):
    for line_list in chess:
        line = line_list[0]
        line = line.replace("0", ".")
        line = line.replace("1", "o")
        line = line.replace("2", "*")
        print(line)
```

Edit: thanks to @Muhammad Rizwan for pointing out that replace returns the result.

Comment: fixed that by using index 0, as the list always has one element

Comment: Your code still does not work, you are not setting your replace equal to anything, so the string `line` is never changed.

Comment: .replce function is not inplace. You have to store it's return value to some variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help.
So far I have managed this, but I have no idea how to put numbers at the beginning and at the end of the line like in the picture.

[image]

My new code:

```
    chess =[
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 "],
    ["0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "],
    ["0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 "],
    ["2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 "]]

letters =["a b c d e f g h"]
numbers =["1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"]

def prt(x):
    num_let(letters) 
    for list in x:
        new = list[0]
        new = new.replace("0", ".")
        new = new.replace("1", "o")
        new = new.replace("2", "*")
        print(new)
    num_let(letters)
   
def num_let (y):
    print(y[0])

prt(chess)
```

This gives me this:

```
a b c d e f g h
. o . o . o . o 
o . o . o . o .
. o . o . o . o
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
* . * . * . * .
. * . * . * . *
* . * . * . * .
a b c d e f g h
```

Comment: Updated my answer based on your info.